# Excel VBA clicking button in internet explorer with unique element name

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to create a macro that clicks this button based on the assignment id of 665.

```
<div class="atlas--ui-grid-cell atlasGrid-cell #modules--execGrid-grid-col-action">
<button class="button small btnViewAction atlas--ui-button" type="button" 
data-tracking-value="Action" data-tracking-label="View Action" 
data-tracking-category="Reconciliations" data-attribs-childassignmentid="665" 
data-attribs-reconciliationid="147794" data-attribs-assignmenttype="A" 
data-attribs-assignmentid="665" value="undefined" data-columnname="action">Edit</button></div>
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
Sub ClickBtn()
Const M_URL As String = "example.com"

Dim OB_IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim btn As Object

Set OB_IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
OB_IE.Visible = True
OB_IE.Navigate M_URL

Do Until OB_IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

For Each btn In OB_IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button")
        If btn.innerText = "665" Then
            btn.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next btn
```

I am able to find the class name, but I cannot get it to recognize the unique identifier of 665. I am able to click this if I change **If btn.innerText = "665"** to If **btn.innerText = "Edit"**. However, there are multiple buttons that have "edit" as the text, which is why I am trying to reference the 665. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to reference certain elements such as the data-attribs-childassignmentid="665". Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
  If btn.GetAttribute("data-attribs-childassignmentid") = 665 Then
```

Comment: Works great, thanks! For some reason, it was difficult to find the .getAttribute in my many Google searches.

Answer (score 1):

Try getAttribute and compare.

```
For Each btn In OB_IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button")
    If btn.getAttribute("data-attribs-assignmentid") = "665" Then
        btn.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next btn
```

You say you got the collection by class correctly but shouldn't that be OB_IE.Document.getElementsBy**Tag**Name("button")? The class is more involved than just 'button'.

Comment: Class and Tag both work. However, Class seems to find it immediately where Tag loops through a lot more elements. Anyways, the .getAttribute worked fine. Thanks!